# How to create multiple models from the same form in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-class-based-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a create view used to make a quiz that has the title, author, etc but my quizzes are made up of answer models that are linked to question models that are then linked to this quiz. How do I make a form for creating a whole quiz, including the questions and correct answers, from this?

```
class QuizCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Quiz
    fields = ['title', 'video_link', 'question_amount']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I use crispy forms in the template

```
{% extends "quiz_app/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Quiz</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-blue" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

TIA

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin), which allows you to embed the form of a model inside the form of the parent model, for example, inside your Quiz form, you could have multiple Question forms.

Unfortunately this works only on 2 levels, you need a third one for the answers, you have two options:

- You could create two different forms: the Quiz form, which includes multiple Question forms, and the Question form, which includes multiple Answer forms;
- You could use [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) which allows you to have multiple nested forms.

Here is a brief [tutorial about django-nested-admin](https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-use-django-nested-admin/), the example refrects what you need.

Comment: ah should have mentioned, I was looking for a way so that users can create quizzes rather than via the admin